# How to access Latitude and Longitude as variables from Service?

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble trying to get the latitude and longitude from my Service and store them as variables so I can access them from other classes I'm building. I want to have them equal to the current latitude and longitude of the user and update them through the interval set in the requestLocation() method. I would like to store them as variables as I would like to perform some calculations using them and I have also written a Content Provider/Database Helper in order to store them in my local Sqlite database but can't right now as I cannot access them. Below can be seen my code for my Location service and MainActivity.

**Location Service**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class LocationService extends Service {

    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

    //public double latitude;
    //public double longitude;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback(){

            // Whenever there is a Location Update, this method is where it occurs
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                // Log Result for Longitude and Latitude, call method to receive elsewhere
                Log.d("myLog", "Latitude is: " + locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude() + ", " +
                        "Longitude is: " + locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
                Intent intent = new Intent("ACT_LOC");
                intent.putExtra("Latitude", locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude());
                intent.putExtra("Longitude", locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
                sendBroadcast(intent);
                //double latitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
                //double longitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        requestLocation();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    // Method to request the Location every 3 seconds
    private void requestLocation(){
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

        LocationService getService(){
            return LocationService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            // If the permission Access Fine Location is not granted
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Request permissions again
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            } else {
                // Start Location Service
                startService();
            }
        } else {
            // Start Location Service
            startService();
        }
    }

    // Start the service with a new intent for the MainActivity and Location Services
    // Register Broadcast Receiver with intent action from LocationService.java
    void startService() {
        LocationBroadcastReceiver receiver = new LocationBroadcastReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("ACT_LOC");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startService();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
    }

    public class LocationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // check if action is required or not
            if (intent.getAction().equals("ACT_LOC")) {
                double lat = intent.getDoubleExtra("Latitude", 0f);
                double lng = intent.getDoubleExtra("Longitude", 0f);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Latitude is: " + lat + ", Longitude is: " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a custom binder. Bind to the service and call a getter (which you need to create)

Comment: I have created the binder just now but still get an error when trying to access from locationCallback and onLocationResult?

Comment: instead of starting the service You need to bind to it. Did you do that?

Comment: No ive just created a local binder. Where do i bind to the service?

Comment: here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services